# Using Regex and Replace function in JavaScript to add semicolon in the end of html entities

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add semicolon to HTML entities in JavaScript.
I wonder if I can use Regex. So far I learned `/ /g`.

```
item.replace(/&trade/g,'&trade;')
item.replace(/&reg/g,'&reg;')
```

Is there a way to combine does two that can add semicolon to all the HTML entities?

Comment: You can do something like this: `item.replace(/&reg|&trade/g, '$&;')`. Note that calling `item.replace(...)` does not change `item` - you'd have to assign the result back as `item = item.replace(...)`.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn thanks for replying my question. Is there any regex to look for anything between & and whitespace or from & till end of string?

Comment: `item=item.replace(/&(#[0-99]+|[a-z]+)/gi,'&$1;');`

Comment: Why are your HTML entities missing semicolons in the first place?

Comment: The tool I am using doesn't let me use semicolons even they are in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://regexr.com

Edit thanks to @Crayon Violent:

```
item.replace("/(&\w+)/g", "$1;");
```

`\w` matches `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`.

---

The cheat sheet is handy :P

```
item.replace("/(&\w+?)\W/g", "$1; ")
```

Added `\w` for letters `+?` to match as few as possible letters(at least 1 letter). Added `\W` at the end to stop matvhing letters when there isn't a letter. Then I added `( )` to make a capture group which I referenced with `$1`.

Comment: couple friendly notes: **1)** `\w+` and `\w+?` will always effectively match the same thing in this context, so if we were to get super anal about efficiency, it would be better to leave `?` off. **2)** `\W` is not necessary because it is the opposite of `\w` and `\w` will never match for something that isn't a word. **3)** to be clear, `\w` matches a *word* character, not just a *letter*.

Comment: to expand on point 1: `\w+?` will still match as many word chars as it can. But what happens is it forces the engine to move forward and see if matching the next char breaks rest of pattern. Since you don't actually have anything else in the pattern that could potentially break from it. Meanwhile, `\w+` just matches everything it can and *then* backtracks giving stuff up if necessary to fulfill rest of pattern. Which again, it never will since there's nothing more to your pattern relevant. So it's actually more efficient to keep it greedy for this pattern.